# How can I read HDFS files from a spark executor?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs

I have a large (> 500m row) CSV file. Each row in this CSV file contains a path to a binary file located on HDFS. I want to use Spark to read each of these files, process them, and write out the results to another CSV file or a table.

Doing this is simple enough in the driver, and the following code gets the job done

```
val hdfsFilePathList = // read paths from CSV, collect into list

hdfsFilePathList.map( pathToHdfsFile => {
  sqlContext.sparkContext.binaryFiles(pathToHdfsFile).mapPartitions { 
    functionToProcessBinaryFiles(_)
  }
})
```

The major problem with this is that the driver is doing too much of the work. I would like to farm out the work done by `binaryFiles` to the executors. I've found some promising examples that I thought would allow me to access the sparkContext from an executor:

[Use SparkContext hadoop configuration within RDD methods/closures, like foreachPartition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224132/use-sparkcontext-hadoop-configuration-within-rdd-methods-closures-like-foreachp)

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/SerializableConfiguration.scala

but they don't seem to work the way I thought they would. I'd expect the following to work:

```
import java.io.{ObjectInputStream, ObjectOutputStream}
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

class ConfigSerDeser(var conf: Configuration) extends Serializable {

  def this() {
    this(new Configuration())
  }

  def get(): Configuration = conf

  private def writeObject (out: java.io.ObjectOutputStream): Unit = {
    conf.write(out)
  }

  private def readObject (in: java.io.ObjectInputStream): Unit = {
    conf = new Configuration()
    conf.readFields(in)
  }

  private def readObjectNoData(): Unit = {
    conf = new Configuration()
  }
}

val serConf = new ConfigSerDeser(sc.hadoopConfiguration)

val mappedIn = inputDf.map( row => {
    serConf.get()
})
```

But it fails with `KryoException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`

Is it possible to have to executors access HDFS files or the HDFS file system directly? Or alternatively, is there an efficient way to read millions of binary files on HDFS/S3 and process them with Spark?

Comment: Try rdd.foreachPartitionAsync() where rdd is input rdd which has path details. (I am not sure if it will solve your problem)

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar use case where i was trying to do the same, but realised 
SparkSession or SparkContext is not serializable thus cannot be accessed from executors.