# Using of hadoop configuration at spark worker

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I want to read some data from Рadoop directly from spark worker:

So, at spark program I have a hadoop configuration:

`val configuration = session.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration`

But I can't use it at worker because it isn't `Serializable`:

```scala
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(paths).mapPartitions(paths => {
      for (path <- paths) yield {
        //for example, read the parquet footer
        val footer = ParquetFileReader.readFooter(configuration, new Path(path), ParquetMetadataConverter.NO_FILTER)
        footer.getFileMetaData.getSchema.getName
      }
    })
```

results in

```
object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any solution to use Configuration object into a mapPartition. refer to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38227538/8357778), you have to rewrite manually your conf into your mapPartition.